# Highlight current line number. [Visual Studio 2019]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to highlight the current line number a seperate color than the rest, like in VSCode?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any options to change how the current line number is rendered, but you can modify the current-line highlight:

[image: Showing current line highlight in lime green]

The setting for this is under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts And Colors, and is called Highlight Current Line.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts And Colors -> Display items: Line Number (Current)

[image: VS 2022 highlight current line number]